# Blend two videos using GPUImage

Tags: ios, gpuimage

Using the latest code of GPUImage from GitHub I tried the following:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GPUImage.h"
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface ViewController ()
{
    GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *filter0;
    GPUImageMovieWriter *movieWriter;
    GPUImageMovie *movie1, *movie2;
}
@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSLog(@"started");

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"video1" withExtension:@"MOV"];
    movie1 = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:url];
    movie1.playAtActualSpeed = YES;

    NSURL *url2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"video2" withExtension:@"MOV"];
    movie2 = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:url2];
    movie2.playAtActualSpeed = YES;

    filter0 = [[GPUImageNormalBlendFilter alloc] init];
    [filter0 forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(1080, 1920)];

    [movie1 addTarget:filter0];
    [movie2 addTarget:filter0]; // movie2 adding Filter

    GPUImageView *filterView= (GPUImageView *) self.view;
    filterView.fillMode = kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio;

    [filter0 addTarget:filterView];

    [movie1 startProcessing];
    [movie2 startProcessing]; // movie2 startprocessing
}
@end
```

Basically, I want to blend two videos and display it on the screen, but after running, nothing gets displayed, only black screen is being shown **and the first frame of the 2nd video is shown after few seconds.**

** I have added the "Header Search Path" and also given the flag **-ObjC** in "Other Linkers"

Now if I add a PixellateFilter to any one of the video(say movie1, commenting **movie2 adding Filter** and **movie2 startprocessing** then the result is coming.

So my question is why the blend is not happening for two videos, am I doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are currently some problems with the playback and blending of more than one movie source. Differences in timebases and the lack of any synchronization mechanism in the two-input filters means that you'll most likely see artifacts when trying to blend two movies. This may or may not be the source of the problem here, but it is something you will encounter until this gets enhanced.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"abc" withExtension:@"mp4"];

gpuIM = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:url];

gpuIM.playAtActualSpeed = YES;

NSURL *url2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"def" withExtension:@"mov"];
movie2 = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:url2];

movie2.playAtActualSpeed = YES;

filter0 = [[GPUImageColorDodgeBlendFilter alloc] init];

[gpuIM addTarget:filter0];
[movie2 addTarget:filter0];

[filter0 addTarget:_view0];

[gpuIM startProcessing];
[movie2 startProcessing];
```

Another approach would be create a avasset from URL , use it in GPUImageMovie,most importantly make the GPUImageMovie instance global.